# How can I get into the UK ASAP and stay as long as possible?

Tags: uk, international-travel, london

Desire to live with my partner and make a life together. She already lives out there and is a resident, whereas I am in the US (America) and still need a passport/visa. Am I able to go there on a Visitation visa and get married with her? From what I researched seems there's all sorts of silly stipulations like being together more than 2 years already and having proof/having to go back and forth with short term visitation visas til I can then apply for a long term visa... Please help. Am trying to get to the UK as soon as possible.

Comment: I wanted to stress that it is really important that you take some time and don't rush into this, I'm no expert but I suspect that if you wrote that on a visa application it would be immediately thrown out. Any requirements may seem silly - but they will have there reasons and you'll need to meet them. If you get this application rejected, it will be harder for you to get a subsequent one accepted. Although I wish you luck, as your question is about immigration I'd recommend trying Expatriates.

Comment: As a US citizen you don't need a visa to visit Britain so you could _visit_ more or less immediately if you have a passport. If you want to marry and/or live in Britain you need to apply for an appropriate visa. You might think that ridiculous, but you have to play by their rules.

Comment: Careful you can't go on a tourist visa/visa-free and get married! There's a special visa for that.

Comment: Any mention of "as soon as possible" or time pressure will doom a visa application.

Comment: Couldn't be simpler - (A) this afternoon, she flies to the US.  (B) walk to the marriage office and get married.  (C) Essentially, you can now go live in the UK after doing some paperwork.